# Refextract library constant error message

Tags: python, macos, pdf, reference

I have an issue using the [refextract library](https://pypi.org/project/refextract/). Every time I try to run these lines of code:

```
from refextract import extract_references_from_url
references = extract_references_from_url('https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07589.pdf')
```

or these:

```
from refextract import extract_references_from_file
references = extract_references_from_file('/Users/antoniya/Desktop/Documents/uni_stuff/FU/Job/Pablo/Jasna_object_recognition.pdf')
```

I get the following error message:

> SystemError: mmap: resizing not available--no mremap()

I had issues with importing the library but managed to fix this, however, I am new to programming and I don't understand what this error message means. Can someone provide me with resources on how to tackle this issue? I was wondering if it's a problem that I am using Mac OS?